# How to call a scenario from other scenario present in separate feature files? i.e. Feature1.feature Scenario1 Feature2>>scenario2

Tags: python, bdd, scenarios, python-behave

In Behave, for python
How to call a scenario from other scenarios present in separate feature files? i.e.
In Feature1.feature file
    Scenario1
       Feature2.scenario2
       Feature3.scenario3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling scenarios from scenarios is not supported by Gherkin and thus not possible.

What you can do is call a strep implementation from another step. Calling steps from another step is, however, an anti-pattern and not a good idea. It will lead you down a bad path.

What you want to do is to call a helper method from both step implementations. I.e. move the desired functionality from a step to a common helper method and use that functionality from both steps.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to call steps, not scenarios(which is a collection of steps). Use [execute_steps](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/api.html#behave.runner.Context.execute_steps) to call steps directly from other *behave* steps.